# Non-linear current-controlled resistor

Tags: resistors, pspice

I am trying to make a current-controlled resistor in  OrCAD pspice, so that R = I^2, where I is the current going through the resistor. I have tried to implement it using a voltage-dependent current source, but I always run in to a problem with floating nodes. Here is the netlist and error message.

```
**** INCLUDING SCHEMATIC1.net ****
* source TESTS
R_R1         0 N08058  1k TC=0,0 
V_V1         N08058 0 10Vdc
G_G1         N07933 0 VALUE { V(N07933,0)/I(V_V4)**2 }
G_G2         N09209 N09253 VALUE { V(N09209,N09253)/I(V_V3)**2 }
V_V3         N08058 N09209 0Vdc
V_V4         N09253 N07933 0Vdc

**** RESUMING test.cir ****
.END

ERROR(ORPSIM-15142): Node N07933 is floating

ERROR(ORPSIM-15142): Node N09253 is floating
```

I have tried to figure out where I going wrong, but the I don't know how to fix it without altering the behaviour of the circuit. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

To try to make the resistor I made the circuit below for testing. It works when I only have one resistor, but when I put them in series, I get in trouble.

[image: My circuit]

Comment: You have two current sources in series. To be more clear: the same way you can't put two voltage sources in parallel (without adding anything else), you can't put two current sources in series.

Comment: Ok. Thank you? Is there a better way to implement the functionality that I want?

Comment: http://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-modeling-constant-power-loads.html

Comment: You can put large value resistors across the current sources, but it still may not converge.